# tracking evolution of an illness with Python nltk and SQL

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, postgresql, twitter

I have many gigabytes of Facebook / Twitter / RSS data.

I am using it to track in a very general way over a generalized population the evolution of hyperparathyroidism from the type someone is diagnosed with something through the medications they've been taking, therapies, and end results.

I am new to the NLTK and I do have great Python / SQL experience.

All of my data has `parathyroid` in it; however, as you can see below *(sample twitter data)*, it is linguistically horrible:

```
omg i think my parathyroid is screwed up!!!
Have been stuck at parathyroid hormone. STOP GETTING ON TWITTER JASMINE.
Cryopreservation of Parathyroid Tissue after Parathyroid Surgery for Renal Hyperparathyroidism
The Parathyroid as a Target for Radiation Damage
it's for the parathyroid hormone la
```

All of this data is stored in a database. We also have fields like poster, post ID, post text, etc.

I was wondering if someone could point me into the right direction for the following:

1. Are there effective algorithms in place already to help me do what I need?
2. Linguistically, how can we find correlations in the data? We are trying to track down patterns.
3. Is there some kind of "grid" form that I should be putting the data into, to help with analysis?

Comment: How do you deal with sampling bias?

Comment: @JoelCornett thank you for asking. that is the challenge. i dont know yet